# Ambiguous Template Instantiation due to Non-Type Parameter Specialization

Tags: c++, list, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to implement lists and their operation by using TMP.

The following code does not compile, `Insert_t` fails to be instantiated (last line):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int... I>
struct List;

template <int Em, typename TList>
struct Append;

template <int Em, typename TList>
using Append_t = typename Append<Em, TList>::type;

template <int Em, int... I>
struct Append<Em, List<I...>> {
  using type = List<Em, I...>;
};

template <int Em, int Idx, typename TList>
struct Insert;

template <int Em, int Idx, typename TList>
using Insert_t = typename Insert<Em, Idx, TList>::type;

template <int Em, int... I>
struct Insert<Em, 0, List<I...>> : Append<Em, List<I...>> {};

template <int Em, int Idx, int H, int... I>
struct Insert<Em, Idx, List<H, I...>> : Append<H, Insert_t<Em, Idx-1, List<I...>>> {};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert_t<4, 4, List<0, 1, 2, 3>>, List<0, 1, 2, 3, 4>>);   // OK
static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert_t<-1, 3, List<6, 3, 1, 4>>, List<6, 3, 1, -1, 4>>); // Fails
```

The g++ compiler gives the following errors, clang provides the same errors. I don't understand why the instantiation is ambiguous as I provide a specialization where the index is 0:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Insert<-1, 1, List<1, 4> >’:
main.cpp:27:8:   recursively required from ‘struct Insert<-1, 2, List<3, 1, 4> >’
main.cpp:27:8:   required from ‘struct Insert<-1, 3, List<6, 3, 1, 4> >’
main.cpp:21:7:   required by substitution of ‘template<int Em, int Idx, class TList> using Insert_t = typename Insert::type [with int Em = -1; int Idx = 3; TList = List<6, 3, 1, 4>]’
main.cpp:30:61:   required from here
main.cpp:27:8: error: ambiguous template instantiation for ‘struct Insert<-1, 0, List<4> >’
  27 | struct Insert<Em, Idx, List<H, I...>> : Append<H, Insert_t<Em, Idx-1, List<I...>>> {};
     |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:24:8: note: candidates are: ‘template<int Em, int ...I> struct Insert<Em, 0, List<I ...> > [with int Em = -1; int ...I = {4}]’
  24 | struct Insert<Em, 0, List<I...>> : Append<Em, List<I...>> {};
     |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:27:8: note:                 ‘template<int Em, int Idx, int H, int ...I> struct Insert<Em, Idx, List<H, I ...> > [with int Em = -1; int Idx = 0; int H = 4; int ...I = {}]’
  27 | struct Insert<Em, Idx, List<H, I...>> : Append<H, Insert_t<Em, Idx-1, List<I...>>> {};
     |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:27:8: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Insert<-1, 0, List<4> >’
main.cpp:18:8: note: declaration of ‘struct Insert<-1, 0, List<4> >’
  18 | struct Insert;
     |        ^~~~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Insert<-1, 2, List<3, 1, 4> >’:
main.cpp:27:8:   required from ‘struct Insert<-1, 3, List<6, 3, 1, 4> >’
main.cpp:21:7:   required by substitution of ‘template<int Em, int Idx, class TList> using Insert_t = typename Insert::type [with int Em = -1; int Idx = 3; TList = List<6, 3, 1, 4>]’
main.cpp:30:61:   required from here
main.cpp:27:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct Insert<-1, 1, List<1, 4> >’
  27 | struct Insert<Em, Idx, List<H, I...>> : Append<H, Insert_t<Em, Idx-1, List<I...>>> {};
     |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct Insert<-1, 3, List<6, 3, 1, 4> >’:
main.cpp:21:7:   required by substitution of ‘template<int Em, int Idx, class TList> using Insert_t = typename Insert::type [with int Em = -1; int Idx = 3; TList = List<6, 3, 1, 4>]’
main.cpp:30:61:   required from here
main.cpp:27:8: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct Insert<-1, 2, List<3, 1, 4> >’
main.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<int Em, int Idx, class TList> using Insert_t = typename Insert::type [with int Em = -1; int Idx = 3; TList = List<6, 3, 1, 4>]’:
main.cpp:30:61:   required from here
main.cpp:21:7: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct Insert<-1, 3, List<6, 3, 1, 4> >’
  21 | using Insert_t = typename Insert<Em, Idx, TList>::type;
     |       ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:30:20: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  30 | static_assert(std::is_same_v<Insert_t<-1, 3, List<6, 3, 1, 4>>, List<6, 3, 1, -1, 4>>);
     |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I want to implement an Insert<Em, Idx, TList> operation to insert a new element Em inside the list TList at position Idx. In my implementation I have provided a template partial specialization for `Insert<Em, 0, List<I...>>` so that the type provided in the struct is the same of `Append<Em, TList>`. However, it is considered ambiguous with the other partial specialization `Insert<Em, Idx, List<H, I...>>`. I don't understand why, as the first partial specialization should be mode restrictive, and how to fix this.

Comment: Why do you assume that first is necessarily more restrictive than the other one? The second one requires the sequence of integers in the list to be non-empty. You can utilize SFINEA restrictions for class specializations and disable the second one when `idx == 0`.

Comment: Easy peasy with C++20, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ze446Sc5m8wSGF39 (with thanks to @ALX23z)

Comment: @PaulSanders while it compiles... currently using concepts to restrict partial specializations of class is not supported by C++ standarts. Only function templates.

Comment: Why use templates for this at all? Just implement constexpr functions. You can even convert between your approach and the constexpr functions in C++20: https://godbolt.org/z/EzbMaGqGz

Comment: @ALX23z C++20 [\[temp.class.spec\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.class.spec#4) "A class template partial specialization may be constrained"?

Comment: @aschepler guess then cppreference requires a fix.

Comment: @fabian the whole point is to learn TMP, not write production level code. It's merely an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You miss one case:

```
template <int Em, int H, int... I>
struct Insert<Em, 0, List<H, I...>> : Append<Em, List<H, I...>> {};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o87e5sh4K)